# Is double return a valid syntax?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I am reading a blog on a certain website.

In his code he is loading data from app state using firebase.
As you can see in his code. He is making double return statement.
Is that a `valid` syntax. if `valid` what does it return? function or value?

```js
export const loadState = (): AppState => {

  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val() as AppState;
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: _"He is making double return statement"_ - No, it's one `return` per function.

Comment: @Andreas So he is only returning `snapshot.val() as AppState;` value right.

Comment: The second return is from the .then: `function(snapshot) { return snapshot.val() as 
 AppState; }`

Comment: The syntax itself seems wrong. Why are there 2 `}` after `return snapshot.val() as AppState`? The `)` should come before the `}`. Also, the `loadState` function doesn't return `AppState`. It returns a promise. So, `(): AppState` isn't correct either.

Comment: `loadState` returns a `Promise` that will resolve with the value of `snapshot.val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make your code a little bit better to read

```
export const loadState = (): AppState => {

  if (firebase.auth().currentUser.uid) {
    let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database()
      .ref('/users/' + userId)
      .once('value')
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val() as AppState;
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Now you will see that the second return is inside an inline function which is the *successCallback* for the Promise which is returned by Firebase.

`firebase.database()` returns a `Promise`. The `ref()` and `once()` methods are chain functions which receive the `Promise` and return a new `Promise` which is then ultimatively passed to the `then()` chain. Your callback returns a new `Promise` which then is returned as `Appstate` to be the return value of the `loadState` function. So `loadState` returns a `Promise` as well.

Read more about [Promises on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
Read more about [Firebase Database API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database?hl=en)

Comment: So the first function is a promise, that we need to return in order to use the value. Using `then` clause will resolve that promise , which in term `snapshot.val() as AppState` will return value to be able to use for `loadState`.

Comment: `AppState` might be a `Promise` in itself.

Comment: Ty for answering. Just last one.
I am still returning a promise right since i am returning `AppState`

Comment: @Khant That's right. I edited my answer on this topic. What the example is missing is a catch